# What we should do when the result is only significant to one country but the whole sample?

Tags: econometrics, subsampling

In a staggered Difference-in-Differences setting, [Dasgupta, 2019](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article-abstract/32/7/2587/5079300?redirectedFrom=fulltext) has a formula for such a static setting is

$Y_{it}$ = $\alpha$ + $\beta$ $pt_{kt}$ + $\delta$$X_{ikt}$ + $\theta$$_t$ + $\gamma$$_i$ +$\epsilon$$_{it}$ *(1)*

where $i$, $k$, and $t$ index firms, countries, and years respectively. $X_{ikt}$ is a vector of the different firm, country, and industry control, while $\gamma$ and $\theta$ are firm and year fixed effects.

When replicating table 3 in his paper, I focus on columns (2) and (6). In these two columns, I have the same control variables sets, fixed effects sets, but only difference in sample. While columns (2) controlled for the whole sample but column (6) controlled for non-US sample.

[image]

As we can see from the Table, the coefficients of $pt_{kt}$ tell us the effect of laws stronger in US countries but weaker in non-US countries. So, I need to address this issue

What I tried is that I add US_dummy equalling to 1 to specification (2) if this firm is in the US to the equation. But I faced the omitted issue because the the information in US_dummy is carried by the year fixed effect already.

That said, **I simply cannot solve the *weakened results in non-US sample* problem by using the US_dummy in all regressions.
Can you suggest me any other way to deal with this issue?**

Comment: What's the issue that you would like to address? What did you hope to achieve by including a dummy for U.S. firms? Do you want a separate effect for U.S. firms only?